# Laravel Route not working. Did not get The id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have now working on a project called Hospital & Doctor Information. Here I have different Division in Bangladesh & in each division there are districts in which there are certain types of hospital according to their ownership. But when I get the value of different hospital from it shows me some error.It did not find the specific id.I Have asked the ques before. But it did not solve my problem. So I ask this again. My route file

```
Route::get('/district/{id}', array('as' =>'district' ,'uses' => 'UserController@district'));

Route::get('/district/hospital/{id}', array('as' =>'hospital' ,'uses' => 'UserController@hospital'));

Route::get('/district/hospital/hospital_info/{id}', array('as' =>'hospital_info' ,'uses' => 'UserController@hospital_info'));
```

My Hospital Info Blade file is

```
<?php $active="hospital"; ?>
@extends('layouts.dashboard')
@section('content') 

    <section id="blog" class="container">
        <div class="center">
            <h2>Hospital Information</h2>
            <h3 class="lead">The government approved a renowned hospital and improved quality of service address , doctor , patient viewing time, bed , pathological tests in various subjects including costs and find the information here .<br> The bed and cabin bookings online , pathological tests , the doctor can be a serial for the meeting from the app .</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="blog">
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="blog-item">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 blog-content">

                                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive img-blog" src="images/2.jpg" width="100%" alt="" /></a>
                            </div>
                            @foreach($division->districts as $district)
                                @foreach($district->cats as $category)
                                    @foreach($category->hospitals as $hospital)
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 blog-content">
                                        <h2>{{ $hospital->name }}</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endforeach
                            @endforeach
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 blog-content">
                                <h2><a href="#">Share</a></h2>
                                <ul class="social-share">
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <br><br>

                                <a class="btn btn-success readmore" href="#">Booking</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                    </div><!--/.blog-item-->\
                </div><!--/.col-md-8-->

            </div><!--/.row-->
        </div>
    </section><!--/#blog-->
@stop
```

My Controller Is

```
public function district($id)
    {

        $divisions = Division::all();

        $division=Division::find($id); 

        $district=District::find($id); 

        // $districts=District::where('division_id', '=', $divisions->id)->get();

        if (!$division)
        {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException;
        }
        return view('users.district')
                    ->with('divisions',  $divisions)
                    ->with('division', $division)
                    ->with('district', $district);
    }


    public function hospital($id)
    {

         $divisions = Division::all();
         $division=Division::find($id); 

         $district=District::find($id); 

         $categories=Category::all();

        // $districts=District::where('division_id', '=', $divisions->id)->get();

        // if (!$district)
        // {
        //     throw new NotFoundHttpException;
        // }
        return view('users.hospital')
                    ->with('divisions',  $divisions)
                    ->with('division', $division)
                    ->with('district', $district)
                    ->with('categories',$categories);
    }


    public function hospital_info($id)
    {
        $divisions = Division::all();
         $division=Division::find($id); 

         $district=District::find($id); 

         $categories=Category::all();
         $cats=Category::find($id); 
         $hospitals=Hospital::find($id); 

        // $districts=District::where('division_id', '=', $divisions->id)->get();

        // if (!$district)
        // {
        //     throw new NotFoundHttpException;
        // }
        return view('users.hospital_info')
                    ->with('divisions',  $divisions)
                    ->with('division', $division)
                    ->with('district', $district)
                    ->with('categories',$categories)
                    ->with('cats',$cats)
                    ->with('hospitals',$hospitals);
    }
```

The Model Hospital iS

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Hospital extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'division_id',
        'district_id',
        'category_id',
    ];

    public function district()
    {

        return $this->belongsto('App\District');
    }
}
```

The District Model Is

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class District extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=[
        'name',
        'division_id',
    ];



    public function division()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Division');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasmany('App\Categories');
    }
    public function dcategory()
    {
        return $this->hasmany('App\Dcategories');
    }

    public function hospital()
    {
        return $this->hasmany('App\Hospital');
    }
}
```

The Division model is

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class Division extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function districts()
    {

        // $divisions = Division::all(); 
     //    $division_id = Input::get('id');
        return $this->hasMany('App\District','division_id');
    }
}
```

The error is
[image]

I have asked the question a few days earlier but did not find the answer. Plz help me.

Comment: Check the foreach in your blade file, variable $divisions is a Collection while $division is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Route not working error is Trying to get property of non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545309/laravel-route-not-working-error-is-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object)

Comment: why the division is null. I gave the id in $division. This technique i used before and it worked. But here in hospital_info id did not work. Why? Please help

Comment: try to print division in the controller first to see whether is null or not then pass it to the view.

Comment: Tried it did not  pass to the view. I can not find where the problem is? I did not find specific id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is you're trying to get a hospital from id but you havn't defined any id in Hospital model so first thing first you should add id column to your Hospital model.

Secondly change your function from this

```
public function hospital_info($id)
{
    $divisions = Division::all();
     $division=Division::find($id); 

     $district=District::find($id); 

     $categories=Category::all();
     $cats=Category::find($id); 
     $hospitals=Hospital::find($id); 

    // $districts=District::where('division_id', '=', $divisions->id)->get();

    // if (!$district)
    // {
    //     throw new NotFoundHttpException;
    // }
    return view('users.hospital_info')
                ->with('divisions',  $divisions)
                ->with('division', $division)
                ->with('district', $district)
                ->with('categories',$categories)
                ->with('cats',$cats)
                ->with('hospitals',$hospitals);
}
```

To this

```
public function hospital_info($id)
{
    $hospital=Hospital::find($id);
    $divisions = Division::all();
    $categories=Category::all();


    // $districts=District::where('division_id', '=', $divisions->id)->get();

    // if (!$district)
    // {
    //     throw new NotFoundHttpException;
    // }


    return view('users.hospital_info') , compact('divisions','categories', 'hospital');
}
```

then you can get your infromation like this

```
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 blog-content">
                                <h2>{{ $hospital->name }}</h2>
                            </div>

             @foreach($divisions as $itemDivision)
                        @foreach($categories as $itemCategory)
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 blog-content">
                                <h2>{{ $itemDivision->name }}</h2>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
```

To get all the information about a District for example :

You should add the (id) column to all your models for using them later 
inside your function do this :

```
public function district($id)
{
    $district=District::findorfail($id); 
    $hospitals = DB::table('hospitals')
    ->leftjoin('districts' ,'hospitals.district_id' , '=', 'districts.id')
    ->where('district.id','=',$id)
    ->select('hospitals.*')
    ->get();



    return view('users.district'),compact('district','hospitals') ;
}
```

Of course the hosptials is an array of objects and you should use a loop to get each hospital's informtaion

Comment: I have tried your code but id did not work. I Did not find the id so id did not work in my route. Please Help

Comment: Ok look instead of returning the view do return of response of all your values and copy them I'd help you

Comment: Look I edited the code now please try it and tell me if it's worked

Comment: I did not get you. I need to return the view. Why I would return response

Comment: Tried. Gives me the same error. I did not find the specific id. So It gave me this error.

Comment: Ok I've understood all you problems just wait for two minutes I am modifying the code again ))

Comment: tnx it worked. Thank You so much. But I cannot Go to the link from my route. Whenever I Goes from route it gives me same error but it gives me same error. But when I put the link staticly it worked . Would You please tell me how can I write this dynamically

Comment: Which link exactly are you talking about ? dynamically pass the id through a foreach loop it would do that but I don't understand the link you're trying to get into

Comment: I did not find all the name of a specific id. Would You please help me to get all the value of a specific id

Comment: You mean you want all the information about a specific hospital ?

Comment: No I mean I want to get all the name of the hospital that belongs to a specific division & district.

Comment: Please check up the code again )) and please submit the answer as correct )

Comment: Ii did not solve my problem.I need the Hospital from district. I have shown the district  on a specific division. Now I need to show the specific hospital info  on specific district. Your code does not satisfy my question

Comment: My friend I gave you an example since I don't know your Division model and you need to to add id's to each table that's why I couldn't give you exact function )

Comment: I added the division model. Please see this.